# How to ignore(/hide) attributes of class in JSON response

Tags: java, json, rest

I am new to Java RESTful web services. I have classes structure as following:

```
    class BaseClass{
        String basicInfo; 
    }

    class DataClass extends BaseClass{
        String id;  
    }   

    class DataList extends BaseClass{
        List<DataClass> dataList;
    }
```

when I get DataList class as Response of web-service, I get it in following format:

```
    {
        "basicInfo" : "Mandetory",
        "dataList"  : [
                {
                    "basicInfo" : "Optional",
                    "id" : "I_1001"                 
                },
                {
                    "basicInfo" : "Mandetory",
                    "id" : "I_1002"
                }
        ]

    }
```

But I want to ignore "basicInfo" attribute in every Data Object of dataList.

ex.

```
{
        "basicInfo" : "Mandetory",
        "dataList"  : [
                {
                    "id" : "I_1001"                 
                },
                {
                    "id" : "I_1002"
                }
        ]

    }
```

Is there any way through which I could ignore these attributes(using annotations)?

Note : I can't change the class structures.

Comment: What library or tool are you using? (Jackson? something else?). Please edit your question and add these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @JsonIgnore

the above is the annotation you require. for more variations of this you can go through the following [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html). add the above annotation to the fields which you wish to ignore in your transfer object and it will be ignore when parsing. Since you haven't mentioned which library you are using to work with json, i have answered your question **using Jackson Library**.

Comment: This requires that the OP must use Jackson for JSON binding.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi yes that's true. that is the reason why i mentioned him to go through the link so that he'll understand what's suitable for him.

Comment: I suggest to tell the OP upfront, in case the link becomes obsolete in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAX-B annotation `@XmlTransient` on your attribute `basicInfo`.

Alternatively, when JSON-B (JSR 367) will be available (Java EE 8), you can use the `@JsonbTransient` or, even better, the `@JsonbVisibility` attribute.